# Help explain this Boolean equation XOR with NOR gates

Tags: logic, computer-science

I'm just starting Boolean algebra and am following an example given in the text that shows the configuration of NOR gates to create an XOR. I cannot follow the algebraic example and would like to have detailed steps filled in as I cannot match up rules I know to the example:

[Example of XOR to NOR algebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKCza.jpg)

$$\color{silver}{\boxed{\color{black}{\begin{align}
A ~\overline B + \overline A ~B ~=&~ \overline{~\overline{~A ~\overline B~}~} + \overline{~\overline{~\overline A ~B~}~}
\\[1ex] = & ~ \overline{~\overline A + B~} + \overline{~A + \overline B~}
\end{align}}}}$$

I understand that (AB)' = A'+B' but I'm not following how the complements were worked out in the example (see jpg) to get the end equation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $\overline{\overline X}=X$ by the law of double negation. Then
$$\eqalignno{
A \overline B + \overline A B &= \overline{\overline{\left(A \overline B\right)}} + \overline{\overline{\left(\overline A B\right)}}
&{\rm by~double~negation}
\cr&= \overline{\left(\overline A + \overline{\overline B{}}\right)} + \overline{\left(\overline{\overline A} + \overline B\right)}
&{\rm by~DeMorgan}
\cr&= \overline{\left(\overline A + B\right)} + \overline{\left(A + \overline B\right)}.
&{\rm by~double~negation}
\cr
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint when its $(AB')'=A'+B$ and  $(A+B')'= A'.B$ where $" ' "$ represents bar.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that (AB)' = A'+B' but I'm not following how the complements were worked out in the example

$$\begin{align}
A~B'+A'~B ~=&~ \Big(\color{navy}{\big(A~B'\big)'}\Big)'+\Big(\color{navy}{\big(A'~B\big)'}\Big)' & \because X = \Big(\color{navy}{\big(X\big)'}\Big)'
\\[1ex] = & ~ \big(\color{navy}{A'+B}\big)' + \big(\color{navy}{A+ B'}\big)' & \because \color{navy}{\big(X~Y'\big)'} = \color{navy}{X'+Y}
\end{align}$$